# Как подсчитать числа априорных повторов в таблице уникальных значений?

Tags: python, excel, pivot

Исходные данные: два столбца повторяющихся значений, например:

| id | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | AA |
| 1001 | BB |
| 1001 | AA |
| 1002 | AA |
| 1003 | BB |
| 1003 | CC |

Нужно получить таблицу уникальных значений с числом повторений, например:

| id | AA | BB | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1002 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1003 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Пытался решить в Excel Python сводными таблицами.
В Python `DataFrame.pivot` требуется `values`, которое и нужно автоматически рассчитать.

Какие еще есть функции?

Comment: При помощи модуля Pandas это делается в одну-две строки кода

Comment: Counter из itertools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

при df:

```
     id Event
0  1001    AA
1  1001    BB
2  1001    AA
3  1002    AA
4  1003    BB
5  1003    CC
```

используем `pandas pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd

df["count"] = df["Event"]
res = pd.pivot_table(df, values="count", index="id", columns="Event", aggfunc="count").fillna(0).astype("int")
```

тогда res будет:

```
Event  AA  BB  CC
id               
1001    2   1   0
1002    1   0   0
1003    0   1   1
```

Comment: Спасибо, изумительно и надежно.

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=["id", "Event"])
res = df.assign(x=1).pivot_table(index="id", columns="Event", values="x", fill_value=0)
res.to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

однострочник:

```
(pd
 .read_excel(filename, usecols=["id", "Event"])
 .assign(x=1).pivot_table(index="id", columns="Event", values="x", fill_value=0)
 .to_excel("result.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Спасибо. Універсально, лаконічно

Comment: @AlexandrSzpinkowski [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)